# Convergence of approximate solution sequence to measure valued solution for incompressible Euler equation

Tags: measure-theory, hyperbolic-pde, fluid-dynamics

I recently studied the measure valued solution of incompressible Euler equations.

In Majda and Bertozzi's book ‘[Vorticity and Incompressible Flow](https://doi.org/10.1017/CBO9780511613203)’:

Theorem 12.10. Let $\{v^\epsilon\}$ be an approximate-solution sequence for the 3D Euler equation such that
\begin{gather*}
|v^\epsilon|_{L^\infty(\Omega)}\leq C \\
\int\int (\phi_t\cdot v^\epsilon+\nabla\phi : v^\epsilon\otimes v^\epsilon)dxdt \to 0  \ \ \text{as} \ \ \epsilon\to0
\end{gather*}
for all $\phi\in C^\infty_0(\Omega)$ with $div\phi =0$.
Then the Young measure $\nu_{x,t}$ associated with the sequence $\{v^\epsilon\}$ is a measure-valued solution of the 3D Euler equation.

We already know there is a Young measure $\nu_{x,t}$ with respect to a subsequence of $\{v^\epsilon\}$ by the Young Measure Theorem.

My question is why do we have convergence
\begin{align}
\int\int (\phi_t\cdot v^\epsilon)dxdt\to \int\int \phi_t\cdot \langle v_{x,t},\lambda\rangle dxdt\\
\int\int (\nabla\phi : v^\epsilon\otimes v^\epsilon)dxdt \to \int\int \phi_t\cdot \langle v_{x,t},\lambda\otimes\lambda\rangle dxdt?
\end{align}
In addition, I have confused the meanings of
\begin{align*}
\langle v_{x,t},\lambda\rangle \ \ \text{and}\ \ \langle v_{x,t},\lambda\otimes\lambda\rangle.
\end{align*}
I guess that
\begin{align*}
(\langle v_{x,t},\lambda\otimes\lambda\rangle)_{ij}=\int\lambda_i\lambda_j dv_{x,t}(\lambda).
\end{align*}
But the problem is that this Young measure is vector-valued.

Comment: TeX note: for pairings, please use $\langle v_{x, t}, \lambda\rangle$ `\langle v_{x, t}, \lambda\rangle`, not $<v_{x, t}, \lambda>$ `<v_{x, t}, \lambda>`.  Note the difference between, for example, $2\langle v_{x, t}, \lambda\rangle$ and $2<v_{x, t}, \lambda>$.  I have edited accordingly.